# Forms with two buttons, only one works

Tags: java, javascript, forms

I have a page with two buttons for creating a pdf and an excel. But only one of them will work. The forms are nearly the same. How can I make both buttons work. Maybe with an id for the forms? Javascript?

```
<portlet:actionURL var="createExcel">
<portlet:param name="action" value="createExcelorConstrainSearch" />
</portlet:actionURL>
<portlet:actionURL var="createPdf">
<portlet:param name="action" value="createPDForConstrainSearch" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<form:form commandName="tg35FormBackingModel" action="${createExcel}" method="post">
<form:form commandName="tg35FormBackingModel" action="${createPdf}" method="post">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
```

....

```
</form:form>
</form:form>

<button type="submit" name="PDF"></button>
<button type="submit" name="EXCEL"></button>
```

Comment: don't nest your forms, and put one button inside each form.

Comment: It's really the same form, only different actions and different buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `name` property to the form, which will make them both work (but not at once). You can check which one was pressed server-side, by reading which `name` value was sent along with the form data.

Comment: Like this: `request.getParameter("name"))`, with `name` being the value of the `name` attribute of the button.

Comment: I already have a if (request.getParameter("EXCEL") != null), but maybe I need the same name on the form?

Comment: Now I have separated the two forms, but then I have two identical forms under one another. How can I make so that the second forms reads the values of the first and is hidden?